# Send two Form objects to the view layer - FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

The crud controller code generated by the symfony2 standard edition (for Edit operation) is like:

```
public function editAction($id)
    {
        // retrieve entity
        $entity= ....
        // create 2 forms (one for editing the current instance and one for deleting it)
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        // Rendering
        return $this->render('StoreTestBundle:Cup:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

But when trying to implement the same behaviour with FOSRestBundle for HTML content, available documentations and examples in the web only take into account returning one Form object:

```
         /**
     * @Annotations\View(
     *  templateVar = "form"
     * )
*/


public function editCupAction($id)
{
    // retrieve object
    $entity= ....
    //return Form object
    return $this->createForm(new CupType, $entity);

}
```

What about adding a second Form for deleting? My goal is to have a final HTML that contains both forms. According to [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#forms-and-views), it doesn't seem possible returning an array of forms will work. Your help is much appreciated.

**After the discussion with Mr Ragdata:**

I ended up getting rid of FOSRestBundle view layer for some of the actions of my controller ( i.e. the GET actions that return forms). I will use manual rendering in such actions because the view layer of the bundle is tieng my hands. According to the view layer documentation, possible ways:

-return a Form from the controller.
-Set the form as only data of the view.
-return an array with a 'form' key, containing a form.
-return a form with validation errors.

I don't fully undertand the second point and if it is related to `setTemplateData()` method, I didn't try it yet...For the moment, I cannot be 100% RESTful( sometimes I should be pragmatic especially when time is lacking).As consequence, following code will not work:

```
public function editCupAction($id)
    {
    ......

     return array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                'edit_form'   => $editForm,
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm,
            );
    }
```

And is replaced by removing `@annotation\view` and using template rendering. So always HTML for these actions, no other format and no content negociation.

*A note about using one form with two buttons:*

isClicked() combined with isValid() will always throw validation errors in this case,  because deleting and editing doesn't deal with common fields (like in the case of SaveAndAdd + Save in cookbook example) so Symfony people are ok not implementing one form with two buttons as I wrongly said. It is very appropriate to have two forms in the code generated by `generate:crud`.

Your remarks are highly welcomed.

Comment: Have you considered modifying your ArticleType class to embed your delete form there?  Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html for ideas

Comment: @Ragdata, thank you for the link..I will read it. It seems embedding the two forms in one before returning is the solution. I will be back here to give feedbacks. thanks again

Comment: Why are you returning a FormBuilder object in your editCupAction? You should first call createView()

Comment: @Frankbeen, It is because I am using FOSRestBundle. My controller extends `FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController`, which allow me to directly return a Form object without creating a view (Of course adding the @annotation/view is mandatory). For the other actions that doesn't use forms, I can directly return entities instead of rendering their specific views...And so on. I hope I could correctly explain  since I am a beginner with this bundle.

Comment: @Ragdata, I have read the link and also the 'embed form collections' from the cookbook. From my humble understanding, embedding forms can be used when we have: 1) extra fields that we need to only validate (but not persist) in order to persist one parent entity or 2) persist child entities in oneToMany or ManyToMany relationships with/or without persisting parent. In my situation, I need 2 separate forms for one entity: one for editing the entity and one for deleting it (with different CSRF tokens). What are you thoughts on that? Do you still believe embedding will be appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain that you do need 2 CSRF tokens.  Give me a while to check out exactly where FOSRestBundle ties your hands (if indeed it does at all) and we'll be able to nut out a solution.

Comment: In the meantime, check out the Symfony docs with regard to [Submitting Forms with Multiple Buttons](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#submitting-forms-with-multiple-buttons) and see if that gives you any ideas

Comment: @Ragdata, I genuinely appreciate the time and the way you grasp documentation in order to take ideas from it. The last idea seems better and I don't know why people of symfony don't implement it in code genrated by `generate:crud` command! About CSRF, I said that because when I inspect elements the two forms have two differents CSRF tokens. I will be back to post the progress as an edit. Thank you very much

Comment: All good Whites ... I appreciate your kind words - thank you.  I have a lot of experience with a myriad of frameworks, and most recently Symfony2.  The one big thing I've learned in my time in this game is that you should never implicitly trust ANYTHING written by anyone else - including the big names in the field.  Sure, Symfony2 has good performance and some nifty toys ... but it's among the clunkier frameworks I've used - and I've noticed they've started to become buried under the weight of their own code.  QUESTION EVERYTHING.  I've got some ideas for you, but I'll wait to see your edit.

Comment: I guess the real point of that little tirade was this.  FOSRestBundle (and any other addon for any framework) introduces another single point of failure for your application and its value to you needs to be carefully and critically analysed.  This is all open source.  If you like one thing in particular, but don't need or feel you will be restricted in any way by the rest of the bundle (and more often than not I've found this to be the case) - steal that one little bit for yourself and discard the rest.  Doing so will also make you more intimately familiar with that critical part of your code.

Comment: @Ragdata, Your last two comments are really the answers to my problem (and will be for all future problems I encounter in my dev career). I am now questionning everything and looking to implement only necessary features from the bundle (since I am not needing them all, as I clearly see now). I will for sure be back here for more verbose technical words. please to accept for now my sincere thanks for your invaluable help.Good night

Comment: @Ragdata. sir! advice understood and small part of it done. In future, I will be trying to analyse bundles more. please to look at my edit when you have time.

Comment: @Whites ... Nice work.  I must admit though that I'm not really any closer to understanding exactly what it is you're trying to do here.  Why RESTful?  Why packaged HTML?  What's your use case? (apologies for not asking earlier)

Comment: @Ragdata, No prob, I maybe don't use the correct words, but what I mean by not being able to build an API 100% RESTful is content-negotiation part (that was managed by FOSRESTBundle) not being anymore applied to `editAction`.Well, I was building a website and rendering everything server-side and only returning HTML. Then I read about data binding and front-end framworks and benefits of JSON so I started returning JSON, then heard that I shouldn't expect browsers as only clients and content negotiation, FOSRESTBundle...

Comment: @Ragdata, .It is honnestly not easy to describe everything in a comment, overall, I am not an expert who is trying to maximize the good practices while fighting with time. I am sure you are finding mistakes in my thoughts but it is due to english not my native language and comments here not the appropriate place to tell everything